# fitting a sine curve R

Tags: r, trigonometry, modeling, lm

The values list below contains annual indices of sunspot activity from 1900-1923. I need to fit a sin curve to this data with a  period of 10.4 years, with lm() in R.
Despite reading other related posts, I couldn't figure this out yet.
The dependent will be the observed values, but for the regressor sin() I am not sure how to set the period as 10.4 years.
Could anyone give me a hint?

```
values <- c(113.5,32.9, 60.3,92.6,503.4,761.6,646.3,744.4, 582.5,526.6,223.0, 68.4, 43.1,17.3, 115.1,568.4,684.8, 1246.7,966.9,763.3,
451.7,313.6,170.9,69.3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Linear vs. nonlinear models

`lm()` is made for models that are linear in parameters, which is not the case of sine models.
Such models can be estimate with `nls()`, which is made for nonlinear models.

## Modeling

The general form of the model would be: y = a + b*sin(c + d*x)

With your hypothesis `d` would be around `2*pi/10.4`, and we can set `a` and `b` to the average y value and `c` to 0.

This results in the following expected fit:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(year = 1900:1923,
             values = values) %>%
  mutate(expected_fit = mean(values) + sin(year * (2*pi/10.4)) * mean(values))

ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data = df, aes(x = year, y = values), color = "blue") +
  geom_line(data = df, aes(x = year, y = expected_fit), color = "red")
```

[image]

## Estimation

We can now use `nls()` to fit this model, specifying our hypothesized parameters for the function to start there.

```
res <- summary(nls(values ~ a + b*sin(c + d*year), data = df, 
                   start = list(a = mean(df$values), b = mean(df$values), 
                                c = 0, d = 2*pi/10.4)))$coefficients

res
```

```
    Estimate  Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
a 442.371777 27.12392790 16.309282 5.093534e-13
b 439.541330 35.88116525 12.249918 9.437063e-11
c  54.939557 26.43198489  2.078526 5.074681e-02
d   0.575082  0.01382716 41.590751 6.740719e-21
```

## Visual check

We can now check that `nls` converged towards appropriate coefficients by computing and plotting the fitted values from this model.

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(fit = res["a", 1]+res["b", 1]*sin(res["c", 1]+res["d", 1]*year))

ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data = df, aes(x = year, y = values), color = "blue") +
  geom_line(data = df, aes(x = year, y = fit), color = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, based on the above I figured the lm version:

year <- seq(1900,1976,1)
model.lm <- lm(values ~ sin(2*pi*year/10.4))
summary(model.lm) 

It seems to be a reasonably good fit, with both beta_0_hat and beta_1_hat significant/ not zero in the model.